# RecyclerView with Contextual Action Mode to delete an item issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8eQ_3pmT6Y in my app to delete recylerview items.
 when I long press on an item, the delete icon will appear on the toolbar and a check box for every row to select an item to delete. But the problem is, when I check first check box Tenth checkbox is also checked check box 2 checks 11th check box and so on. 
does anybody have any idea why its happening. This is my adapter and activity code sorry if it's to long

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.contentViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Heyvon> heyvons = new ArrayList<>();
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    Context context;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Heyvon> heyvons) {
        this.context = context;
        this.heyvons = heyvons;
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public contentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        contentViewHolder contentViewHolder = new contentViewHolder(view, mainActivity);

        return contentViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(contentViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(heyvons.get(position).getPics());
        holder.name.setText(heyvons.get(position).getName());
        holder.ghaza.setText(heyvons.get(position).getGhaza());
        if (!mainActivity.isInActionMode) {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return heyvons.size();
    }

    public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<Heyvon> list) {
        for (Heyvon heyvon : list) {
            heyvons.remove(heyvon);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class contentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name, ghaza;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        CardView cardView;

        public contentViewHolder(View itemview, MainActivity mainActivity) {
            super(itemview);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            name = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_names_card);
            ghaza = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_ghaza_card);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            cardView = (CardView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            cardView.setOnLongClickListener(mainActivity);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mainActivity.prepareSelection(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Code in Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_delete) {
        isInActionMode = false;
        ContentAdapter contentAdapter = (ContentAdapter) adapter;
        contentAdapter.updateAdapter(selectedlist);
        ClearActionMode();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        ClearActionMode();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return true;
}

public void ClearActionMode() {
    isInActionMode = false;
    toolbar.getMenu().clear();
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    counter_text_veiw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    counter_text_veiw.setText("0 item is selected");
    counter = 0;
    selectedlist.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    toolbar.getMenu().clear();
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_action_mod);
    counter_text_veiw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isInActionMode = true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    return false;
}

public void prepareSelection(View view, int position) {
    if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
        selectedlist.add(heyvons.get(position));
        counter = counter + 1;
        updateCounter(counter);
    } else {
        selectedlist.remove(heyvons.get(position));
        counter = counter - 1;
        updateCounter(counter);
    }
}

public void updateCounter(int counter) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        counter_text_veiw.setText("0 item is selected");
    } else {
        counter_text_veiw.setText(counter + " item is selected");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isInActionMode) {
        ClearActionMode();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is very likely to be due to `RecyclerView`'s recycling: when you select an item in the list the `CheckBox` is updated but if you scroll and the selected view gets recycled you will see a different (unwanted) one checked. In your case the `RecyclerView` could be usgin a `Pool` that is 9 elements big: the first view is recycled to display also the 10th and so on.

This means that the view in which the checkbox was selected is filled with data from another item in the list according to `onBindViewHolder()` and it is displayed at the opposite side of the screen instead of creating a new one. Obviously the `CheckBox` remains wrongly checked.

It is also probable that a previously selected item after some scrolling will appear unchecked.

In `Adapter`'s `onBindViewHolder()` you need to reset `CheckBox` state depending on whether the item has actually been selected (this method is called every time a view inside of the `RecyclerView` is created or recycled):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(contentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(heyvons.get(position).getPics());
    holder.name.setText(heyvons.get(position).getName());
    holder.ghaza.setText(heyvons.get(position).getGhaza());
    if (!mainActivity.isInActionMode) {
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Uncheck everything
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Has this item been selected?
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(mainActivity.isSelected(position));
    }
}
```

in `MainActivity` you could keep track not only of the selected objects but also of their position in the `Adapter`  by using a `List`, `Set` or array:

```
private List<Integer> selectedItemsPositions;
```

prepareSelection should keep the selected item's position:

```
public void prepareSelection(View view, int position) {
    if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
        selectedlist.add(heyvons.get(position));
        selectedItemsPositions.add(position); // Keep track of the position
        counter = counter + 1;
        updateCounter(counter);
    } else {
        selectedlist.remove(heyvons.get(position));
        selectedItemsPositions.remove(position);
        counter = counter - 1;
        updateCounter(counter);
    }
}
```

and `isSelected()` would be defined like this:

```
public boolean isSelected(int itemPosition) {
    return selectedItemsPositions.contains(itemPosition);
}
```